# Convert select Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I´m trying to apply this script http://blog.iamjamoy.com/convert-select-boxes-to-a-fancy-html-dropdown which convert a  element into a bootstrap drodown

It breaks on IE in this line

$(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {

this is the code

```
$this.each(function(i, e){
        if (!($(e).data('convert') == 'no')) {

            //get some initial data...
            xSelect = $(e).attr('id');
            xLabel =  $("#"+xSelect +  " option:selected").text();
            xClass =  $(e).data('class');

            $(e).hide().wrap('<div class="btn-group" id="xSelect-group-' + i + '" />');
            var select = $('#xSelect-group-' + i);

            select.html('<a class="btn dropdown-toggle '+ xClass + '" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;">' + xLabel + ' <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul><input type="hidden" value="' + $(e).val() + '" name="' + $(e).attr('name') + '" id="' + $(e).attr('id') + '" class="' + $(e).attr('class') + '" />');

            $(":checkbox", this)
            $(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {
                    select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="javascript:;" data-title="'+ $(q).text() +'" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');
                    if ($(q).attr('selected')) select.find('.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + o + ')').click();
            });
            select.find('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
                    select.find('input[type=hidden]').live().val($(this).data('value')).change();
                    select.find('.btn:eq(0)').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            });
        }
    });
```

If anyone could help I'd appreciate

Comment: In the comments of that blog, did you see how one of the comments included a fiddle with an example that works in IE?  http://jsfiddle.net/xuAQv/13/

Comment: yes I have seen it, but did not worked

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this JavaScript plugin](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select). It hides the `select` and adds a dropdown button into the HTML.

It works very good for me. I tested on IE8 and it works.

Comment: Thank you - documentation does not make this explicit.